# useSelector or useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

My question is rather an opinion-based than fact-based.
I'm wondering what can be a better practice, My scenario is as follows:
I have a react component (which is a parent component) who uses some `useSelector` to fetch store data and it has many children.

What is the best approach to consume data from the component `children`?

- Wrap the parent component with `React.useContext()` and pass it to the `<*Context*.Provider/>`, and consume it as `<*Context*.Consumer/>`
- Use `useSelector()` inside the children to fetch the data from the store.

Both of them will keep the data memoized, so I'm not worried about that...
Both of them seem pretty good approach, I'm wondering what are the edge-cases for each of them?

Comment: The way I have done this in the past is to use `useSelector()` on your parent component and pass it as props to the children. So that parent component is just a container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use both (because `useSelector` uses the Context API under the hood). That's why you have to have a parent [`<Provider store={store}>`](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#using-hooks-in-a-react-redux-app) element in order to use `useSelector`.

So I think the easiest way would be to do `useSelector` and let React Redux worry about the Context API.

Comment: You are right, I think that we need to use context API just when we want to add extra values to the children component then (query params etc..).

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same question less that a week ago, according to me:

- use the first one when the component that is using the data need to be updated when the data changes, using a consumer will re render the component when the consumed data changes anywhere in the application
- Use the second one when you're just updating the data or just don't care if the data changes at a later time

Comment: Both of your points are valid for either approach because the approaches are the same.

Comment: prefer consumer when you want the consuming component to re render itself; that is the point.